# Edit Manage Subscription Page

Tags: reporting-services

I have SharePoint 2010 with SSRS integrated. When I right click on a report and select Manage Subscriptions I am presented with a list of the current subscriptions. The columns are:

Type, Delivery Extension, Description, Event, Last Run, Last Results.

How do you edit this Manage Subscriptions page to add another column that includes the Last Modified date for the subscription?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There wouldn't be anyway out of the box to edit the existing page to include what you are looking for.  You would have to do some custom work to query this information and display it on a custom page (or web part or SSRS report) of your own.